# Using Ext.data.Model statics values in field defaultValue

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

Today I faced with a problem about Ext.js statics properties.
I tried to initialize model field with some *static* value, but it throws me an error, that model is *undefined*. As I understand this problem is related to object lifecycle (how objects are creating), but have no idea how to fix it.

```
Ext.define('app.model.base.Ticket', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

    statics: {
        SOME_STATIC_VALUE: '1231231'
    },

    fields: [
        {
            name: 'requesterName',
            defaultValue: app.model.base.Ticket.SOME_STATIC_VALUE
        }
    ]
});
```

Error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'SOME_STATIC_VALUE' of undefined
```

Did anybody hack this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
Ext.define('app.model.base.Ticket', (function() {
    var foo = '1231231';
    return {
        extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

        statics: {
            SOME_STATIC_VALUE: foo
        },

        fields: [
            {
                name: 'requesterName',
                defaultValue: foo
            }
        ]
    };
})()
);
```